# Warum bedeutet »draufgehen« sterben?

Tags: etymology, slang

*Draufgehen* bedeutet umgangssprachlich *sterben*.
Aber warum? Ich konnte keinen klaren Zusammenhang dafür finden.

Comment: Draufgehen tun meistens die Draufgänger ;)

Comment: Sterben ist nur eine von vielen Bedeutungen - verbraucht werden (Geld, Ersparnisse) oder kaputt gehen (Gegenstände) sind ebenfalls häufige Bedeutungen. Im Sinne von verbraucht werden finde ich zumindest [eine Quelle aus 1688](https://books.google.de/books?id=rvhlAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA329&lpg=PA329&dq=%22draufgehen%22+ursprung&source=bl&ots=rawVWNYQTL&sig=o5LS39TWBLw3vJTlVbjjMtqH5jA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-g7LFpd3aAhWIKsAKHVZABf0Q6AEIQzAE#v=onepage&q=%22draufgehen%22%20ursprung&f=false), dieses Wort ist also schon recht alt, aber keine weiteren Angaben zur Herkunft.

Comment: Diese Quelle von 1688 ist doch schon mal ein interessanter Hinweis. Die Herkunft könnte also eine Wendung "X geht auf Y" sein, im Sinne von "Die Ausgabe X wird verursacht/getragen von Y". Man vergleiche den Ausdruck "Die Rechnung geht aufs Haus".

Answer (score 4):

[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GD00570#XGD00570) verzeichnet die Bedeutung unter Punkt 5a von *darauf*:

> schwinden, durch kosten aufgezehrt werden, zu grund gehen.

und bringt das Beispiel:

> bei dem frost sind alle weinstöcke draufgegangen

Warum-Fragen sind bei Sprachthemen immer etwas schwierig zu beantworten. Meine Theorie ist, wie von @RHa im Kommentar angeregt, dass es mit Buchhaltung zu tun hat. Etwas wird auf ein bestimmtes Konto geschrieben bzw. gebucht und ist damit erledigt.

Answer (score 3):

Ich stelle hier zusammen, was das Deutsche Wörterbuch der Gebrüder Grimm (= DWB) **im Artikel "gehen"** dazu schreibt. Es zieht eine Linie von '*irgendwo daraufgehen = daraufpassen*' über den Zusammenhang mit '*Kosten-*' oder 'Vermögensschaden-*Aufstellung*' *= 'aufgewendet werden müssen'* zu '*sich ganz verbrauchen*' und so '*verloren gehen*'.

Das Wörterbuch unterscheidet 36 nummerierte Haupt-Bedeutungsfelder des Verbs *gehen*. Die nächste Gliederungsebene sind lateinische Buchstaben, unterhalb deren wird weiter mit  griechischen Buchstaben unterteilt.
Die Abschnitte zu d(a)raufgehen sind unter "17)" zu finden:

http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG04934#XGG04934
[hier mit STRG+f nach "17)" (mehrere Treffer) oder besser nach "verwuchs" suchen]

Zu "gehen"  sind unter 17) a) und b) Verwendungen in der Bedeutung "**möglich, zu machen sein**" versammelt. Es handelt sich um Kontexte wie 'die Tür geht nicht richtig zu', allgemeiner auch im Sinne von '**irgendwo hinein-, hindurch-, auf, über, an etwas passen oder Raum haben**' (Beispiel Adelung nach Grimm in aktueller Rechtschreibung: *der Wagen geht nicht durch das Tor*), c) auch verabsolutiert in 'das geht' oder 'das geht nicht' (= ist (nicht) machbar).

Das d) **'irgendwo hinpassen'** gibt es β) **auch mit 'darauf' und 'auf'**. Beispiel aus DWB: "*ein wagn mit waitz, drauf ein mut gieng*" = ein Wagen mit Weizen, auf den ein Muth ging (Muth = altes Raummaß).

In 17) e) heißt es: "hier erklärt sich wol auch das merkwürdige **gehen auf** .., **drauf gehen, von kosten, aufwand der erfordert wird** u. a." Beispiel: 17) e) α) "*24 groschen o. ä. [gehen] auf einen thaler.*"

Weiter in 17) e) β): "**diesz drauf gehn dann auch von kosten, auf einen gewissen zweck**:"

1. "*zum kosten, der auf das opfer gehet.* 1 Macc. 10, 39." [Gemeint
   hier: Kosten, die für das / als Opfer aufgewendet / gespendet
   werden.]
2. "*was jerlich auf die opfer gienge ..* 2 Macc. 9, 17" [= was jährlich
       als Opfergabe **aufgewendet = weggegeben** wird];   "_sampt allem
       costen und schaden, die doruf gangen (auf unterhaltung des
       gepfändeten viehes)._weisth. 4, 205" [= samt aller Unkosten und
       finanzieller Nachteile, die darauf gegangen = **aufgewendet (und
       verloren)** sind];
3. "*mer hab ich in .. verkauft .. 2 sawen von Ach .. und sol ausrichten*
           (auslegen) *was darauf geht gen Wien.* OTT RULAND 32, d. h. was die
           lieferung bis Wien noch erfordert" [= ich habe ihm mehr (= außerdem)
           verkauft … 2 Säue von Ach (= Ort oder Person) und soll auslegen was
           draufgeht = **an Kosten entsteht** bis nach Wien]
4. "*was auf den wexel gangen* .. 36 gld. BREUN. V. BUCH. 83, in der
       kostenberechnung für den herz. v. Würt. von seinen geschäften in
       London, [=] 'was beim geldwechseln drauf gegangen ist'." [= durch (zusätzliche) Wechselgebühren oder Verluste beim Währungstausch (?)]
5. "nachher für **verloren oder zu grunde gehn**, genauer: **sich
       aufreiben über** einem verfolgten zwecke: *sie (die katze) leckete
       aber so lange, bisz die zunge ganz darauf gieng.* OLEAR. Lokm. 26"
6. "*bis alles darauf gangen ist*" [= bis alles **verbraucht (und
       verloren)** ist];
7. "*ihr geht drauf, wenns so fortwährt* LENZ 1, 221." [= ihr **werdet**
       darüber ganz **aufgerieben**, wenn es so weitergeht].
8. "etwas anders: *so gehts mit unsern herrn (liebhabern) in dieser schlimmen zeit, es gehen zwanzig drauf, bis dasz ein halber freit.* GÖTHE 7, 51 (mitsch. 1, 3)" [= unter 20 Liebhabern, die 'verloren(e Liebesmüh)' sind, ist nur ein halber, der auch heiraten würde.]

Anm.: Die ursprünglichen Text-Hervorhebungen wie Kursivschrift wurden geändert und durch Fettdruck ergänzt.

Answer (score -1):

Ich denke der Zusammenhang kommt daher, dass ein "Draufgänger" jemand ist, der keine Gelegenheit, in welchem Kontext auch immer, auslässt.

Ein Draufgänger kann auch mal draufgehen, bei einer risikohaften Begebenheit.

Comment: Das ist nicht abwegig, jedenfalls gibt es eine ganze Reihe von Redensarten mit 'draufgehen wie': http://proverbs_de.deacademic.com/4257/Draufgehen . Heute würde man soweit ich weiß eher sagen 'rangehen wie'. Allerdings ist dieses 'drauf' in 1 'draufgehen wie' ein anderes als in 2 'draufgehen bei/für'. 1 bezeichnet ein buchstäbliches 'Sich-auf-etwas-Werfen', 2 ein 'Mit-verbraucht-Werden'.